# Как заменить div средствами js?

Tags: html, замена

Покажите на примере как заменить на странице div:

```
<div id="new_message"></div>
```

на

```
<div>Некий текст</div>
<div id="new_message"></div>
```

желательно средствами js.

Comment: а где тут происходит замена div'а? Вижу добавление нового дива с текстом перед дивом с идентификатором. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Это так выглядит что добавление... а нужна именно замена первого дива на другие 2 дива.

Comment: из привиденного примера это не ясно

Answer (score 3):

Создаем новый `div`, добавляем в него текст, находим родителя блока `new_message`, и добавляем созданный `div` перед `div` с `id="new_message"`

```
var el = document.getElementById('new_message');
var parentEl = el.parentNode;
newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.innerHTML = 'Некий текст';
parentEl.insertBefore(newEl, el);
```

Comment: Как добавить в созданный div class?

Comment: @Юрий, newEl.setAttribute("class", "your_class_name");